# Error 1120 when defining StyleSheet

Tags: css, actionscript-3, stylesheet

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.StyleSheet;

public class BattleActionButton extends MovieClip
{
    public var buttonID:int = 0;

    var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
    css.parseCSS('battleactionbutton { font-family: Pixelade; font-size: 4px; text-align: justify; color: #000000;}');
```

Above I've pasted the entire class that's giving me the problem. This is my first time using CSS in AS3, so I imagine I've got a problem somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `parseCSS` call into the constructor, like this:

```
var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

public function BattleActionButton() {
    css.parseCSS('battleactionbutton { font-family: Pixelade; font-size: 4px; text-align: justify; color: #000000;}');
}
```